# List view auto reload while some one other add data in Firebase database table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wants to create an app where online conversation will happen. I do it by using of `Firebase`. I connect the `Firebase` and can able to add data in database table in multiple device.
Problem is inserted data is only visible from the device who have inserted it in database table. Rest of the other device cannot view it automatically. It will visible while that device insert a new data in database table. I am sending my code in following. Please have look.

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.swatin.firebaselistviewsaveretriveshow.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="openAddArea"
    android:id="@+id/topbutton"
    android:onClick="openBellowtopbutton"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bellowtopbutton"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topbutton"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add"
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"/>

</LinearLayout>



<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bellowtopbutton"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
DatabaseReference db;
FirebaseHelper helper;
EditText nameEditTxt;
Button saveBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    helper=new FirebaseHelper(db,this);
    nameEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText) ;
    saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //GET DATA
            String name=nameEditTxt.getText().toString();
            //SET DATA
            Spacecraft s=new Spacecraft();
            s.setName(name);
            //VALIDATE
            if(name.length()>0 && name != null)
            {
                if(helper.save(s))
                {
                    nameEditTxt.setText("");
                    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,helper.retrieve());
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,helper.retrieve());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, helper.retrieve().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
public void openBellowtopbutton(View view)
{
    LinearLayout bellowtopbutton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bellowtopbutton);
    if(bellowtopbutton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        bellowtopbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        bellowtopbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
 }
}
```

Spacecraft

```
public class Spacecraft {
String name;
public Spacecraft() {
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
}
```

FirebaseHelper

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved=null;
ArrayList<String> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db,Context context) {
    this.db = db;
    this.context = context;
}
//WRITE
public Boolean save(Spacecraft spacecraft)
{
    if(spacecraft==null)
    {
        saved=false;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            db.child("Spacecraft").push().setValue(spacecraft);
            saved=true;
        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved=false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
//READ
public ArrayList<String> retrieve()
{
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            Toast.makeText(context, "callMe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return spacecrafts;
}
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    spacecrafts.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {   String name=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class).getName();
        spacecrafts.add(name);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A custom adapter implementation would do it but I recommend to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library that has already done it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you. Can you explain it once more.

Comment: Instead of using an `ArrayAdapter` you should create a new implementation of `BaseAdapter` and inside access Firebase. That is the way to back list views with new data sources. Even better is to not do it on your own and use a `RecyclerView` with the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` of the previously [mentioned](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) library. It works almost out-of-the-box. Just follow the docs! Hope that helps.